# Javascript - Set a DIV size without having to wait the page end of load

Tags: javascript, html, load, resize

I have a DIV I want to adjust its size regarding the window size. So I have a javascript method that returns the newsize to apply. But I don't see how I can define that size to the div without having to wait the end of page load.

I mean, I have some long loading objects on the page, so if I use the window.onload way to set the size, I have a div with a bad size at the start, then when the page is loaded, the div is resized. Baaad looking.

I'd like to set that size as soon as the page is displayed, with something like :

```
<div id="myid" style="width:myjavascript_Getcorrectsize();">
```

How would I do such a thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to wait for the `window` `load` event, or even for the "ready" events that some libraries provide. Just put your script block *after* the `div` in question, and you will be able to access that `div` via the DOM to set its size. E.g.:

```
<body>
  <div id="target">This is the target, JavaScript makes it 100px wide</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var elm = document.getElementById("target");

      elm.style.width = "100px";
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/ajezak)

References:

- [Google Closure library engineers on when elements are available](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)
- [YUI Best Practices to Speed Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

That said, if you can possibly set the size via CSS, you'd be better off. But I expect you've already found that for some reason you can't do that.

Comment: Not necessarily... what about images and such that haven't fully loaded yet?

Comment: Bullet proof solution. images will load normally and would not affect the DIV size.  Well done T J Crowder

Comment: @landons: The `img` elements will be there; the image data may not yet be (and so if you're querying their width and height, they won't be there yet). You'd have to hook their `load` event and their `complete` flag if you were dependant on the image data.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method is to insert a `<script>` block at the end of your document, and execute the desired code:

```
...
<script>
(function(){ //<-- This part is optional, but recommended if you don't want
             // to leak variables to the global scope
    document.getElementById("myid").style.width = myjavascript_Getcorrectsize();
})();
</script>
</body>
```

If you want the element to have a specific relative width, you can also use relative units instead of JavaScript:

```
<div id="myid" style="width:50%">
```